# Chrome blocking Java plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, java-applet

When I use Chrome with a certain page, I get the following message shown in a yellow bar along the top of my screen:

> The Java plug-in was blocked because it is out of date.

I have the following options:

- Update plug-in...
- Run this time
- X [to close the bar, effectively saying "don't upgrade, don't run it"

I can't upgrade the plugin due to system policy.

If I click on the X to get rid of the bar, is there a way to later on choose the "Run this time" option?

Comment: Why do you want to run an out-of-date Java and risk having your system compromised? Your IT support people should update Java on your system.

Comment: I completely agree, but the fact is that my IT support *won't* upgrade Java on the system - I'm stuck on Windows XP and IE6, plus Chrome. Joy.

Answer (score 1):

If you reload the page, I believe chrome will ask again for the plugin...

But instead of incessantly facing that prompt, run chrome with `--allow-outdated-plugins` command line switch. Let me warn you that this is not secure though.

Answer (score 0):

To let the plug-in run on the site, follow these steps:

To run the plug-in just this once, click Run this time in the message. The plug-in will run, but if you re-visit the site, you'll be asked for permission to run the plug-in again.
To always allow the current site to run the plug-in, click Always run on this site. Subsequent visits to the site will run the plug-in without asking again.